# OracleSQL - not a single-group group function - Do I need to join 2 seperate queries?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

So im currently doing a project and im doing the final question for Oracle SQL, in which i need to:

"Display the publisher name, bookcategory, book ISBN number, book title, and book retail price (formatted with ‘$’and 2 decimal places) for all books that have been sold the most from all
categories which have fewer than three available titles from the bookstore."

So essentially, I have the following code:

```
SELECT p.name, b.category, b.ISBN, TO_CHAR(b.retail, '$99.99')"Retail price"
FROM Books b, Orderitems o, publisher p
WHERE b.pubid = p.pubid
    AND b.ISBN = o.ISBN
HAVING COUNT(b.category) > 3
```

and i get an error saying line 1 is not a single group function, if i change it to AND instead of having I get an error saying "Group function not allowed here".

If anyone could point me in the right direction i would be thoroughly grateful as I'm not quite sure how to proceed!

Thank you very much!

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: `GROUP BY  b.category, b.ISBN, TO_CHAR(b.retail, '$99.99')`?

Comment: Avoid old style joins from the 80s (the `,` in the `FROM` clause). Use modern joins.

Comment: Gotcha! I will change up the joins now so it is more modern :) Thank you!

Comment: @Hybrid1000 can you please add some sample data and output so that i can try to write a simpler query for you.

Comment: Would it be best to add an screenshot of the ER Diagram? Or should i copy and paste the tables created into the question? A friend seems to have come up with a solution but I feel like their should be a far easier way @AnkitMongia

Comment: @Hybrid1000 If you give tables and  sample data that will help alot.

Answer (score 0):

Sample data would help; meanwhile, see if this helps.

```
with fewer as
  -- number of available titles
  (select b.isbn, count(*) cnt
   from books b
   group by b.isbn
  ),
data as
  (select p.name,
       b.category,
       b.isbn,
       sum(b.retail) sum_retal,
       rank() over (order by sum(b.retail) desc) rnk
   from publisher p join books b on b.pubid = p.pubid
                    join fewer f on f.isbn = b.isbn 
   where f.cnt < 3
   group by p.name, b.category, b.isbn                 
  )
select d.name, 
       d.category,
       d.isbn,
       d.sum_retail
from data d       
where d.rnk = 1;
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to! I can try and add the data if that would be more helpful :) This seems super above the paygrade of what we have learnt, but maybe i can apply it! :) Thank you very much